# JS Performance issue [Skrollr Lib]

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, load, skrollr

I've been recently trying out a library for js called Skrollr.
I can simply use it for different effects while scrolling a page, such as fade outs, etc.

I faced a real performance issue and at first, i thought it's just because of my images and I tried to compress everything down to just 180mb~! but it lags like hell when you try to scroll.

here is where i think it happens:

```
while (i < Images.length) {

    empty = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    to = Creating(to, 0, Images[i], empty);

    i++;
}
```

and the Creating function is pretty stright forward too!

```
function Creating(from, config, url, name) {

let to = 0;

if (config === 0) {

    $('#slide').append('<div class="item" id="' + name + '"></div>');
    let mydiv = $("#" + name + "");

    //first create a structure for your data with jquery
    mydiv.attr('data--' + from + '-top', 'opacity: 0;');
    from += 800;
    mydiv.attr('data--' + from + '-top', 'opacity: 0;');
    from += 400;
    mydiv.attr('data--' + from + '-top', 'opacity: 1;');
    mydiv.attr('data-anchor-target', '#slide');
    mydiv.html('<img id="img" src="' + url + '"' +
        'style="width: 1000px;">');

    to = from;
```

......bla bla

```
return to;
```

you get the idea.
if the length of my image array is about 100, it sorta works but still not smooth! and the original size of the array is about 250. 
how can I fix this performance issue? any sort of solution is much appreciated.
please visit this repo for the full story: https://github.com/codacy20/SkrollWebsite/blob/master/app.js

Comment: I think the problem hides somewhere in the words "compress down to 180mb". These figures don't usually do well with the display of an HTML page. We talk in Kb here. Browsers engines definitely don't like the idea of repainting 180MB of images.

Comment: well said Jeremy but take a look at this great work by jake. http://jakealbaugh.com/
same as my situation, he uses images (like a lot of images) and he loads even 2 sets of images. high res and low res

Comment: @JeremyThille I think you were right. I went back and checked again. he uses 10 images. I'm using like 200 of them. it makes sense now

Comment: if you have photoshop use "save for web" i think ur problem is mainly because of image size. although your code in not optimized at all.

Comment: by the way he used 200 too.